# Intersection of string field with string array in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a table which resides a string field that is separated by comma and I have a string array. I want to look this comma separated string feild inside the string array. I couldn't tokenize the string feild so that I can look inside string array by "IN" clause. Example is below:

```
String feild = "inbox, outbox, draft, sent";
String[] strArray = ["inbox, "outbox", "sent", "web", "software"];
```

How can I get the intersection of the feild string with the string array?

Comment: Although the string stored on the table is comma separated, it has to be treated as a string. I don't think you can us `IN` in this kind of scenario.

Comment: What approach should I follow in this case, because I coudln't find any work around.

Comment: Actually, I didn't mean to exactly query it by "IN" cluase. I want query it by a similar approach.

Comment: Since the data is a string, you may try `LIKE`.

Comment: I tried LIKE but it cannot match every word in feild string to string array. The intersection is impossible with LIKE.

Comment: Can you convert the strArray to string in the way the field is stored before sending in the query? I am not sure you want to map each word in the strArray or all of them have to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
Criterion c = null;
for(String s : strArray){
    if(c!=null){
        c = Restrictions.like("field","%"+s+"%");
    else {
        c = Restrictions.or(c,Restrictions.like("field","%"+s+"%"));
    }
}
```

it's an inefficient way but it's a solution.

Comment: I tried to solve the problem this way but it is quite expensive. Think about a large string array that has to searched inside a long string feild. It is a solution with no effeciency :)